# How can I make a loop output to two different lists?

Tags: python

I have run into a block in my python code where i'm not sure how to make a loop split an output into two different lists. Here is my code:

```
def GameStart(AmountPlayers):
    players = []

    for player in range(AmountPlayers):
        hand = TakeCards(5)

        players.append(hand)

        print(hand)
        returncard(hand)
```

This function outputs this if `2` is entered for `AmountPLayers`:

```
['blue_skip', 'blue_9', 'green_5', 'green_9', 'red_1']
['yellow_skip', 'green_6', 'yellow_8', 'red_9', 'blue_3']
```

However both of these are outputs of the variable `hand`.
I need to acess these lists separately, so need to find a way of putting each list into separate variables, e.g `hand1` or `hand2`, and so on until hand 4 (the maximum number of players).

Does anyone know a way of doing this?

Cheers

Comment: What is the criteria of splitting the values into the two lists?

Comment: How do you mean criteria? What I am trying to do is access 2 hands made by the GameStart function separately, so that I can use indexes of hand1 or hand2 later.

Comment: You've put them into `players`. Why isn't that enough? See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: What does `returncard` do?

Comment: You can make a list of lists, with the outer lists being the hands, and the inner lists being the cards. Or a dict of lists, with each dict item being a hand.

Comment: @AnshumaanMishra return card essentially concatenates ".png" to the end of each card name.

it outputs:

['red_1.png', 'yellow_4.png', 'red_5.png', 'red_3.png', 'green_9.png']
['blue_6.png', 'yellow_9.png', 'red_9.png', 'red_8.png', 'red_7.png']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the objective is to obtain two lists with cards drawn for that player, this is the code:

```
from random import choice, randint

deck = list(range(1, 11))
def TakeCard():
    global deck
    a = choice(deck)
    deck.remove(a)
    return a
        
def GameStart(AmountPlayers):
    global deck
    numOfCards = 5
    players = [[]for _ in range(AmountPlayers)]
    for _ in range(numOfCards):
        for player in range(0, AmountPlayers):
            players[player].append(TakeCard())
    return players
        
print(GameStart(2))
```

This returns a list of two lists as:

```
[[4, 5, 7, 6, 3], [10, 2, 9, 1, 8]]
```

Replace the elements of `deck` with card names.

#### Optional alternate solution. If you plan on displaying images, use previous one since it allots cards one by one and maybe you can add animations. This one allots all cards to one player at once:

```
from random import choice

deck = list(range(1, 11))
def TakeCards(n):
    global deck
    z = []
    for _ in range(n):
        a = choice(deck)
        deck.remove(a)
        z.append(a)
    return z
        
def GameStart(AmountPlayers):
    global deck
    return [TakeCards(5) for _ in range(AmountPlayers)]
        
print(GameStart(2))
```